# How to manually get initramfs prompt at boot

Tags: arch-linux, boot, hard-disk, manjaro, initramfs

I'm trying to get an initramfs prompt at boot because I have no USB drives or anything that I can use, and I need to use `fsck` on my `/dev/sda`, but that's obviously not allowed while it's mounted. It's not bad enough that I get the prompt, but it still appears to fix a few things every once in a while at boot.
So my question boils down to:
**How can I stop or pause the boot process, on Arch Linux, to get an initramfs prompt?**

(I'm sorry if this isn't possible on Arch, I'm coming from Debian)

Answer (score 0):

Reboot machine and go to recovery mode.
select drop to root shell prompt.

remount file system with below command.
`mount -o remount, rw /`

Then you can run fsck command.

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify a bit? I have grub installed, but as the only OS I have installed is my Manjaro install, GRUB doesn't seem to appear at boot. I assumed you meant recovery mode kernel from the GRUB advanced settings, but I don't have that. Is there another way you meant? A quick google search doesn't show me anything about recovery mode.

Comment: @kel5isgod have you see grub parameters on system boot ?